# How to get an image to show up over a joomla menu bar

Tags: joomla, z-index

I'm trying to get one div containing an image to show up over a joomla menu-bar... The one I want on top is at the bottom of the code called "wings.gif", but for some reason it won't show up over the user3 joomla bar, which I put in a Div. any ideas how to do this? thanks.

```
<div style="position:relative; z-index: 2;overflow: visible;"><jdoc:include >type="modules" name="user3" /></div>
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="banner1" style="artstyle" artstyle="art-nostyle" />
<?php echo artxPositions($document, array('top1', 'top2', 'top3'), 'art-block'); ?>
<div class="art-contentLayout">
<div class="art-<?php echo artxCountModules($document, 'right') ? 'content' : 'content->wide'; ?>">
<div style=" position:relative; "> < src="images/stories/image" width="898" height="126" style="position:relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/></div>
<div style=" position: absolute;top:-50px; left:647px; z-index: 1; overflow: visible; ">< src="images/stories/**IMAGE**" width="199" height="136"  /></div>
```

Comment: ok, apparantly I can't figure out how to post code...

Comment: yes except you should have used "code" instead of "quote". Fixed that for you.

Comment: yes thanks. now as for the question.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I can see from the code you posted, the absolute div you created is the child of one of the children of the "brother" of your user-3 div :D This means that it floats on top of the last relative positioned item in his parent. But it wont magically fly outside the scope of its parent towards your user-3 div.

Advice: Dont start putting things randomly on relative coz this will make your quest even harder, just make the absolute div a child of your user-3 div, or a "brother".

ps: why is brother quoted? I forgot the name of a same-level node and figured the name was suiting... :D